# Most efficient way to get next letter in the alphabet using PHP

Tags: php, string, alphabet

Given any character from a to z, what is the most efficient way to get the next letter in the alphabet using PHP?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

The most efficient way of doing this in *my* opinion is to ***just increment*** the string variable.

```
$str = 'a';
echo ++$str; // prints 'b'

$str = 'z';
echo ++$str; // prints 'aa'
```

As seen incrementing `'z'` give `'aa'` if you don't want this but instead want to reset to get an `'a'` you can simply check the length of the resulting string and if its `>1` reset it.

```
$ch = 'a';
$next_ch = ++$ch; 
if (strlen($next_ch) > 1) { // if you go beyond z or Z reset to a or A
 $next_ch = $next_ch[0];
}
```

Comment: @Mathias there was a minor error with mixing up the pre and post incrementing. Change it to `$b = ++$a;`

Comment: @Mathias: My bad...you should be using pre-increment as: `$b=++$a;`
@nickf: Thanks :)

Comment: Your code sample is incorrect. `$next_ch = $ch++;` will not store the incremented value in `$next_ch`, but *will* in fact increment `$ch`. Confused me there for a sec :) Great tip though, I didn’t know this was even possible. Definitely the most efficient way of doing it!

Comment: you should take the locale into account when doing this. The alphabet is not the same for everybody.

Comment: Is there any way to get previous letter? -- not working

Comment: @itsazzad it seems you must use `chr(ord($ch)-1)`

Answer (score 20):

It depends on what you want to do when you hit Z, but you have a few options:

```
$nextChar = chr(ord($currChar) + 1); // "a" -> "b", "z" -> "{"
```

You could also make use of PHP's `range()` function:

```
$chars = range('a', 'z');  // ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ...]
```

Answer (score 8):

Well, it depends what exactly you want to do with the "edge cases". What result do you expect when the character is `z` or `Z`? Do you want the next letter of the *same case*, or just the next letter, period?

Without knowing the answer to that, for the very basic case, you can just do this:

```
$next_character = chr(ord($current_character) + 1);
```

But when you're at `Z` this will give you `[`, and `z` will give you `{`, according to ASCII values.

---

*Edited as per comment:*

If you need the next character of the same case, you can probably just add simple checks after the line above:

```
if ($next_character == '[')
    $next_character = 'A';
else if ($next_character == '{')
    $next_character = 'a';
```

These are very simple operations, I really wouldn't worry about efficiency in a case like this.

Comment: I want the next letter with the same case. If the character is `z`, i expect `a`.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be faster to just return `A` or `a` immediately when the character is `Z` or `z`?

Answer (score 5):

How about using [ord() and chr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php)?

```
<?php
    $next = chr(ord($prev)+1);
?>
```

Comment: Short and sweet! But what about the edge cases (`z` should return `a`)? Is there a better way to check for this other than an `if ()` statement?

Comment: $next = ($prev == 'z') ? 'a' : chr(ord($prev)+1);

Answer (score 3):

```
$val = 'z';
echo chr((((ord($val) - 97) + 1) % 26) + 97);
```

Nice and easy :-)

Comment: and for 'Z' it is `$next=chr((((ord($c) - 65) + 1) % 26) + 65);` i.e. ord('A')

Answer (score 2):

Since I only care about lowercase characters in this case, I'll use the following code, based on the answers posted here:

```
function nextLetter(&$str) {
 $str = ('z' === $str ? 'a' : ++$str);
}
```

Thanks for the help, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of all letters, search for existing letter and return its next letter. If you reach the last letter return first letter.