# Checking value from database and Incrementing letters

Tags: php, mysql

How I can increment a letters if value already in the database? Just like in my database structure AA, AB, AC and the next value should be AD.

How to check the value and increment the value?

**Database Structure**

```
id  |  code |   
1   |  AA   |  
2   |  AB   |  
3   |  AC   |
```

**Example Code**

```
<input name="maincode" value="<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "2015");

    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT code FROM category
    WHERE code != '' ORDER BY code");

    $var = 'aa';
    do {
      echo $var++.'<br />';
    } while ($var != 'aaa');
```

The next value should be AD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data= "AC";
$data++;
echo $data; //AD
```

you should use google :)

[page 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567180/increment-letters-like-numbers)

[page 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673360/most-efficient-way-to-get-next-letter-in-the-alphabet-using-php)

[page 3](http://joshualuckers.nl/2010/03/02/php-increment-alphabet-characters/)

[Incrementing/Decrementing Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

Now, to select the last value, in this case AC

```
$query = "SELECT code FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

//this should return the last record

**To sum both letter**

[str_split](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-split.php)

```
$data= "AA";
$letter= str_split($data);
$letter[0]++;
$letter[1]++;
echo $letter[0].$letter[1];
```

Comment: what if I have AA and next value should BB? How to do it?